# jQuery animation menu queue problem

Tags: jquery, animation, menu, queue

I've read like 15 topics about it. Finaly I turn my own thing, but.. Look at the code.

```
    $("#top_menu .top_menu_elements>ul>li")
    .mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find(".moreMenu").stop(true,true).show(250);
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find(".moreMenu").stop(true,true).hide(250);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="top_menu">
    <div class="top_menu_elements">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="Site1">Site1</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Site2">Site2</a>
            <div class="moreMenu">
                Bla bla bla menu stuff
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Site3">Site3</a>
            <div class="moreMenu">
                Bla bla bla menu stuff
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And.. It works fine. But try to enter different duration times like show(250) hide(50). When you rush mouse for a while over this menu it goes mad. I've tried callback, things with queue and dequeue, also with stop. Nothing seems to help - sth goes wrong. It should work with different times, but it doesn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code seems to be working fine.

look here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/3vcpE/

Comment: I suppose I should say "sorry" and add "but it was not working" :)
That was a hard day.. Even with different duration it works fine..

So, anyway maybe this solution will help anyone.

Sorry

Comment: @elon its ok, it happens to the best of us ^_^